# Actual exception is not getting logged in MVC when host in IIS

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

I am running one MVC application where i found one exception in specific method. I will provide here complete details about it.

I am loading some third party grid control from view. to load it i used below code:

```html
 @{Html.RenderAction("MasterGridAction", "MyController");}
```

Now when i access this report from development then this view load and it hits this action method where i used some piece of code there it is throwing error, To catch the error i used try catch block in the method where in catch section i used below code to throw the actual exception like below:

```html
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw(); throw;
            }
```

When exception get catched it sends this to the Application_Error method in global.asax page where i used below code to find out the actual exception like below:

```html
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpServerUtility server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
            if (server.GetLastError() != null)
            {
                Exception exception = server.GetLastError();
                if (exception.GetBaseException() != null)
                {
                    exception = exception.GetBaseException();
                    ExceptionType(server, exception);
                }
                else
                {
                    ExceptionType(server, exception);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this ExceptionType method i get the exception stack and log to the file using "Log4Net". After logging to the file i could see the exception in notepad like below:

```html
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source File: /MyController/MasterGridAction

Stack Trace: 
   at 3D.Controllers.MyController.MasterGridAction() in D:\MyUser\3D_MVC\Application\3D_OnlyRelease\3D\Controllers\MyController.cs:line 405
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

As we can see in above exception it is clearly shown the line number also where this exception get caught.
But once i host this application in IIS server and access the same page then i could see the logged file
There it shows exception like below:

```html
Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:    at 3D.Controllers.MyController.MasterGridAction()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

As you can see the logged exception of IIS server is not having much information when compare to other exception details.

Am i missing anything there to get the complete exception when host in IIS?

Please suggest.

Comment: Hello All, Any update on above asked?

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the logged exception of IIS server is not having much information when compare to other exception details.

This could be because you don't include the PDB files in production.

It might not be a great idea to include them, since that way one can reverse engineer you app with more precision if they hack your server, but it is up to you to decide. I have seen organizations that include them in their production environments.

Try publishing and deploying on a test environment with and without the PDB files to verify this.